# Accessing Java class from HTML web app

Tags: java, javascript, html, webcontent

I have a dynamic web project. In `src` folder I have Java class with couple of methods. Let us suppose `index.html` file has two buttons.on click of the button how can I call the Java class. Is there any possibility of doing so?

Comment: Did you try with `JSP`?

Comment: or do you mix up Java with JavaScript (this is not the same). Java should be not used in normal webpages and you should use a Java framework and Java server (which use JSP) - but you can try a Java applet (may not be very secure and blocked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create servlet which will handle get/post requests, invoke your java code and return result.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/819-6518/abxbh/index.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/servlet-142430.html

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using simple html pages. You should be using [JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html) files instead which will let you make a call to your JAVA classes methods through directives.

This is common guess since you did not provide much relevant information about your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSP. Here is a simple tutorial that could be useful to start. [JSP tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should work with frameworks. I recommend you SPRING MVC. It`s very good and easy to use. For calling a java class you need jQuery and the framework.